# How can I merge certain sections of two YAML files into a third YAML file?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have 2 YAML files, 'Config.yaml' and 'MyConfig.yaml', both of which have sections that contain information about a Kubernetes cluster.

Config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters: 
    - name: "name"
      cluster: 
        server: "server"
        certificate-authority-data: "certificate-authority-data"
users:
- name: "name"
  user: "user"
  token: "token"

contexts:
- name: "name"
  context:
      user: "user"
      cluster: "cluster"

current-context: "current-context"
```

MyConfig.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters: 
    - name: "name2"
      cluster: 
        server: "server2"
        certificate-authority-data: "certificate-authority-data"
users:
- name: "name2"
  user: "user2"
  token: "token2"

contexts:
- name: "name2"
  context:
      user: "user2"
      cluster: "user2"

current-context: "current-context"
```

I would like to merge the entries in the 'clusters', 'users' and 'contexts' sections into a third file called NewFile.yaml under these headings. The third file would look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config

clusters: 
    - name: "name"
      cluster: 
        server: "server"
        certificate-authority-data: "certificate-authority-data"

    - name: "name2"
      cluster: 
        server: "server2"
        certificate-authority-data: "certificate-authority-data"
users:
- name: "name"
  user: "user"
  token: "token"

- name: "name2"
  user: "user2"
  token: "token2"

contexts:
- name: "name"
  context:
      user: "user"
      cluster: "cluster"

contexts:
- name: "name2"
  context:
      user: "user2"
      cluster: "user2"

current-context: "current-context"
```

The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
import ruamel.yaml 
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
items = ['Config.yaml', 'MyConfig.yaml']
for item in items:
    with open (item) as fileToReadFrom:
        data = yaml.load(fileToReadFrom)
    with open ('NewFile.yaml', 'a') as fileToWriteTo:
        fileToWriteTo.write(str(data['clusters'])) 
        fileToWriteTo.write(str(data['users']))
        fileToWriteTo.write(str(data['contexts']))
```

I have managed to take the information in the 'clusters', 'users' and 'contexts' sections and put them in the new file. The output is as follows:

```
[{'name': 'name', 'cluster': {'server': 'server', 'certificate-authority-data': 'certificate-authority-data'}}][{'name': 'name', 'user': 'user', 'token': 'token'}][{'name': 'name', 'context': {'user': 'user', 'cluster': 'user'}}][{'name': 'name2', 'cluster': {'server': 'server2', 'certificate-authority-data': 'certificate-authority-data'}}][{'name': 'name2', 'user': 'user2', 'token': 'token2'}][{'name': 'name2', 'context': {'user': 'user2', 'cluster': 'user2'}}]
```

However, the information is not in a YAML format and I am not sure how to get the information into the right sections. Please could somebody help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure Kubernetes does want duplicate keys in a mapping? The YAML specification states that that is an error. If would be bad if Kubernetes ignores it witout throwing an error, even worse if it relies on duplicate keys.

Comment: I recommend always to use a YAML dumper to dump anything beyond completely trivial data. And certainly not append to a potentially already existing file. It is unlikely that you get anything close to valid YAML that way.

Answer (score 0):

The output in `NewFile.yaml`  as you present it is invalid YAML: the root level of that file is
mapping and you cannot have two of the same keys ( `contexts` ) in a mapping. You
can set `yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True`, but that only applies to loading, to not
throw an error (and overwrite one of the keys with the other).

The rest of the output seems to follow the rules that:

- if the value for a key is a scalar (the keys `apiVersion`, `kind`, `current-context`), that
  in the output you have a scalar ( I assume from the `MyConfig.yaml`, although this cannot be
  seen from the example you give
- if the value for a key is a list, the output has a list combining the elments for the list (
  this is done for the keys `clusters` and `users`.

In the following I assume the second rule needs to be done for `context`  as well:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

conf = Path('Config.yaml')
myconf = Path('MyConfig.yaml')
outconf = Path('NewFile.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(conf)
for k, v in yaml.load(myconf).items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        data[k].extend(v)
    elif isinstance(v, dict):   
        # doesn't happen in your example, so it is a guess what to do
        data[k].update(v)
    else:
        data[k] = v
yaml.dump(data, outconf)
print(outconf.read_text(), end='')  # YAML already ends is newline
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
  - name: name
    cluster:
      server: server
      certificate-authority-data: certificate-authority-data
  - name: name2
    cluster:
      server: server2
      certificate-authority-data: certificate-authority-data
users:
  - name: name
    user: user
    token: token

  - name: name2
    user: user2
    token: token2

contexts:
  - name: name
    context:
      user: user
      cluster: cluster

  - name: name2
    context:
      user: user2
      cluster: user2

current-context: current-context
```

If you really need output with double key entries (only one of which you will
be able to access after loading), you need to revert to some trickery and
postprocessing:

```py
data = yaml.load(conf)
for k, v in yaml.load(myconf).items():
    if k == 'contexts':
        k = 'contexts666'
    if isinstance(v, list):
        if k in data:
            data[k].extend(v)
        else:
            data[k] = v
    elif isinstance(v, dict):   
        data[k].update(v)
    else:
        data[k] = v

def makeduplicate(s):
    return s.replace('contexts666', 'contexts')
yaml.dump(data, outconf, transform=makeduplicate)
print(outconf.read_text(), end='')
```

which gives your invalid YAML, but with a slightly different key order:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
  - name: name
    cluster:
      server: server
      certificate-authority-data: certificate-authority-data
  - name: name2
    cluster:
      server: server2
      certificate-authority-data: certificate-authority-data
users:
  - name: name
    user: user
    token: token

  - name: name2
    user: user2
    token: token2

contexts:
  - name: name
    context:
      user: user
      cluster: cluster

current-context: current-context
contexts:
  - name: name2
    context:
      user: user2
      cluster: user2
```

It would be better to figure out which of the duplicate keys is used by
the software processing that invalid YAML incorrectly (assuming the software
does that consistently, which is not necessarily true), and only write the
key-value for that one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this matter - I haven't dealt with the YAML format with Python before. I've taken into account your method of accessing the key-value pairs and then joining together the values and have revised my code accordingly.

Comment: Also, you are correct about the invalid YAML. The heading 'contexts', as you mentioned, was only meant to be there once.